# how to get items that belongs to all numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, compare

I need some analogue to numpy.in1d() function, my task is to have list of items, that more than 2 arrays have. For example i have 3 arrays:

```
a = np.array((1,2,5,6,12))
b = np.array((1,3,7,8,5,14,19))
c = np.array((2,6,9,5,1,22))
```

the result should be [1, 5]

Any faster way than pure cycle using np.in1d to compare first with all the rest? Some unions of arrays or some smart subindexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.intersect1d`.  For example:

```
In [15]: np.intersect1d(a, np.intersect1d(b, c))
Out[15]: array([1, 5])
```

or with `reduce`:

```
In [16]: reduce(np.intersect1d, (a, b, c))
Out[16]: array([1, 5])
```

If you know the elements within each array are unique, use the argument `assume_unique=True`:

```
In [21]: reduce(lambda x, y: np.intersect1d(x, y, assume_unique=True), (a, b, c))
Out[21]: array([1, 5])
```

Answer (score 2):

If each list is unique you can try:

```
>>> total=np.concatenate((a,b,c))
>>> np.where(np.bincount(total)>2)
(array([1, 5]),)

#Might be faster to do this.
>>>bins=np.bincount(total)
>>>np.arange(bins.shape[0])[bins>2]
array([1, 5])
```

If these arrays are large:

```
>>> tmp=np.concatenate((np.unique(a),np.unique(b),np.unique(c)))
>>> tmp
array([ 1,  2,  5,  6, 12,  1,  3,  5,  7,  8, 14, 19,  1,  2,  5,  6,  9,
       22])

>>> ulist,uindices=np.unique(tmp,return_inverse=True)
>>> ulist
array([ 1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 12, 14, 19, 22])
>>> uindices
array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  8,  0,  2,  3,  5,  6,  9, 10,  0,  1,  3,  4,  7,
       11])

>>> np.bincount(uindices)
array([3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> ulist[np.bincount(uindices)>2]
array([1, 5])
```

Comment: unique is a must for me before concatenate, thank you, works great as well, have to compare speedups for different configurations